# TSP with multiple visits

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Can you please suggest possible approaches for the following problem: find a path through graph verticies so that the distance (sum of edges weights) between two vertex i occurrences would be no more than Di. It is obviously infinite, so I want to have a generator for this path.

Answer (score 0):

When your graph satisfy the triangle inequality the christofides algorithm guarantee you to be within 2/3 of the optimum.